# Should I patch or do the whole wall?

Tags: drywall, plaster, patching-drywall

We removed a load bearing wall and installed a header. For this we opened up two walls, Pictures are below. My drywall guys says, patching these two area will standout. He is suggesting that he will plaster the whole wall and put the sand texture on top of it to make the whole wall look even.

Should I do the whole wall or should just patch it?

Patch in beige wall is about 45" in height and 7" wide and red wall is 15" wide and 5' in height.

Thank you.

[image: Patch is 45" in height and 7" wide]

[image]

Comment: Does it have sand texture on it now?

Answer (score 1):

A patch will be virtually undetectable if done properly. Professional plasterers do often skim the entire wall but there is no reason to texture the entire wall if you do not want to.

Using texture is an easy way to hide imperfections, so is a great idea if you (or your contractor) do not want to spend the time and effort (and $$; time = $$) to patch it properly. Call a different "drywall guy", preferably a reputable professional plaster company and one that doesn't leave unscrewed floating corners like in top pic.

Comment: Sharp eyes. Hanging was done by my carpenter. What do you mean by this "Professional plasterers do often skim the entire wall". It has serval coating of paint since the house was built in 60s. He is asking 100$ to do the full wall. I feel like it is not worth the risk but the same time I don't want to be a fool to throw my money away.

Comment: The patch will be flat and smooth - skimming a thin layer of mud, on a larger surface, sometimes the entire wall, blends the existing "bumpy" surface, into the new "flat" surface.

Answer (score 0):

Not to sound harsh but I would think if HE does it, it may stand out. It is good that he knows his limitations. A drywall man that has been in the business for a while will know how to finish a wall and make it blend in. If it is a true sanded finish, with lots of coats of paint over it, he may have a point, then again, it should be a matter of repeating the coats of paint that the surrounding area has. Also in my opinion, if he does what he is suggesting, he is just moving the difference in texture to the corner. A place not as noticeable, but still different...

Comment: Itt has serval coating of paint since the house was built in 60s. He is asking 100$ to do the full wall. I feel like it is not worth the risk but the same time I don't want to be a fool to throw my money away. So you think he is not bullshiiting me?